# Open webpage in app cordova

Tags: cordova

I'm new to this!

I want to include my website as a part of my Cordova-App.
The page(s) should be opened in the app, not in an internal/ external browser, so it looks like they are actually part of the app.

I've tried `window.open(...)` and `window.location="..."`, but it always opens chrome.

Comment: @Homen I want to outsource a part of my app to a website. Say I want to have an "About-Activity" in my app. I would create a link to my-website.com/about/, but rather than opening it in a browser, it should feel like it was a part of the app. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this tag : `<allow-intent href="://example.com/" />` in `config.xml` to `<allow-navigation href="://example.com/" />`

`<allow-intent>` allows to open urls in browser

`<allow-navigation>`allows to open urls inside app